# Disable chrome context menu option on own site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I disable a context menu item created by my own chrome extension within my own site?  For content scripts in a chrome extension, there is the `excludes_matches` option but context menus don't appear to have an equivalent.

I just don't want the context menu item I'm adding to show up when the user is on my own site.

**UPDATE**

People seem to be confused about what I'm doing so here's the code. In my "background_page" I add an item to the context menu like so:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create(
{
    "title": "My Context Menu Item",
    "contexts": ["link"],
    "onclick": myContextItemClicked
});
```

The item shows up when a user right clicks on any `<a>` tag as expected. What I want to do is prevent it from showing up when a user is within my own site.

Comment: Is that working ? `(function disableRightClick()
{
 if(document.layers)
 {
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
  document.onmousedown=function(){if((document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all)&&(e.which==2||e.which==3))return false;};
 }
 else if(document.all&&!document.getElementById)document.onmousedown=function(){if(event.button==2)return false;};
 document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false;");
})();`

Comment: @Mageek I don't want to disable the entire context menu, just my item in the menu.

Comment: you mean your options or popup page?

Comment: @Oliver neither. My extension adds an item to the context (aka, "Right click") menu. I don't want that item to appear in the menu when the user is within my own website.

Comment: hm, according to the api you can only define positive matches, but no exclusions. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved similar problem by triggering menu creation on `mousedown` event in a content script injected to every page. Something like:

content script:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
        if(event.button == 2) {
                chrome.extension.sendRequest({"createMenu"});
        }
}, true);
```

background page:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request === "createMenu") {
                chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
                        if(sender.tab.url != "http://mysite.com") {
                            chrome.contextMenus.create({...});
                        }
                });
        }
});
```

Doesn't look very effective but there is no other way around afaik. It works pretty smooth though so users won't be able to see that you are recreating the menu before displaying it.

Comment: I was speculating something like that might work.  Now I won't be wasting my time :-)  If nobody else posts a more elegant solution in the next 24 hours I'll accept this answer. +1 for now